# Clear selected value(s) for Kendo multi select

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have Kendo multiSelect control which is working perfectly fine. However I am facing issue to reset its selected value. The following is what I have tried so far :

```
$("#Department option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

And

```
var departmentMultiselect = $('#Department').data("kendoMultiSelect");
var subtract = $('#department').val();
                var values = departmentmultiselect.value().slice();
                values = $.grep(values, function (a) {
                 return $.inarray(a, subtract) == -1;
                });
                departmentmultiselect.datasource.filter({});
                departmentmultiselect.value(values);
```

In the second code, control bypasses the following code

```
values = $.grep(values, function (a) {
                     return $.inarray(a, subtract) == -1;
                    });
```

How can I reset this control?

Comment: Shouldn't $.grep filter function have two arguments (viz. the current array item and its index), these are mandatory as doc says.

Comment: What do you mean by reset... unselect any values?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To unselect all values in kendo multiselect:

```
var multiSelect = $('#Department').data("kendoMultiSelect");
multiSelect.value([]);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. You could trim it down more and scrap the var. $('#Department').data("kendoMultiSelect").value([]);

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question, but wanted to remove only one value from the multiselect rather than everything. This is what I came up with:

```
var multiselect = $('#multiSelectId').data("kendoMultiSelect");
var values = multiselect.value().slice();

// optionId is the value I want to remove
var index = $.inArray(optionId, values);
if (index > -1) {
    values.splice(index, 1);
}

multiselect.dataSource.filter({});
multiselect.value(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set's the multiselect to your Placeholder value

```
var multiselect = $("#ICD10CodeIds").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        multiselect.value(0);
```